# Prismatic joint with PositionJointInterface interferes with Gazebo physics

Tags: ros, gazebo, ros-control, gazebo-ros-control

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I working on a simulation model of a forklift using ROS control and Gazebo. I'm using a prismatic joint to simulate the piston moving the forks up and down. Since I added a PositionJointInterface to the joint transmission I have been having issues with the physics. It seams to fix the joint in place. If I put the forklift in the air it hangs there, swinging by the joint, instead of falling down. This does not happen if I use the VelocityJointInterface or EffortJointInterface.

Is this a bug or am I using the position controller incorrectly?

[image: Forklift refusing to fall]

Here is the transmission

```
  <transmission name="lift_transmission">
    <type>transmission_interface/SimpleTransmission</type>
    <joint name="lift1_joint">
      <hardwareInterface>PositionJointInterface</hardwareInterface>
    </joint>  
    <actuator name="lift_motor">
      <hardwareInterface>PositionJointInterface</hardwareInterface>
      <mechanicalReduction>1</mechanicalReduction>
    </actuator>
  </transmission>
```

Here is the joint and link definition

```
  <joint name="lift1_joint" type="prismatic">
    <parent link="forklift_body"/>
    <child link="forklift_lift1"/>
    <axis xyz="0 0 1"/>
    <limit lower="0" upper="3" effort="1000" velocity="0.2"/>
  </joint>
  <link name="forklift_lift1">
    <collision>
      <origin xyz="0 -1.44 0.695" rpy="0 0 0"/>
      <geometry>
       <box size="1.2 0.1 1.25"/>
      </geometry>
    </collision>
    <collision>
      <origin xyz="0.32 -2.1 0.06" rpy="0 0 0"/>
      <geometry>
       <box size="0.13 1.2 0.03"/>
      </geometry>
    </collision>
    <collision>
      <origin xyz="-0.32 -2.1 0.06" rpy="0 0 0"/>
      <geometry>
       <box size="0.13 1.2 0.03"/>
      </geometry>
    </collision>    

    <visual>
      <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0"/>
      <geometry>
       <mesh filename="package://forklift_description/meshes/forklift_lift1.dae"/>
      </geometry>
    </visual>

    <inertial>
      <origin xyz="0 -1.4 0.4" rpy="0 0 0"/>
      <mass value="${lift1_mass}"/>
      <cube_inertia m="${lift1_mass}" w="1" h="1" d="0.2" />
    </inertial>
  </link>
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/256743/prismatic-joint-with-positionjointinterface-interferes-with-gazebo-physics/) by [gudjon](https://answers.ros.org/users/17816/gudjon/) on ROS Answers with karma: 111 on 2017-03-11

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-03-12**:
So without `ros_control` / the `PositionJointInterface` in the mix, everything works?

**Comment by [gudjon](https://answers.ros.org/users/17816/gudjon/) on 2017-03-12**:
Yes, it seems to work with anything but the PositionJointInterface. My current workaround is to use VelocityJointInterface and JointVelocityController.

Now I just noticed that the same issue happens when I use the PositionJointInterface on a revolving joint. That seems weird to me.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-03-13**:
Hm. Interesting. I can't promise you it'll get diagnosed sooner, but perhaps if you create an MWE others can try to reproduce your issue. It would also help if/when you report this to the [tracker](https://github.com/ros-simulation/gazebo_ros_pkgs/issues).

**Comment by [cyborg-x1](https://answers.ros.org/users/1900/cyborg-x1/) on 2017-05-31**:
That sounds like the same problem I have. I am trying to create a model for the Farmbot. A gantry. I thought it already worked. But now I tried to get it working. With the controller the joint it just does weired things, rotating like a helicopter including moving a very heavy dirt block

**Comment by [cyborg-x1](https://answers.ros.org/users/1900/cyborg-x1/) on 2017-05-31**:
First I though I have a inertia problem but when I remove that joints - everything is just fine. I will try your hint to use the other controllers now.

**Comment by [SorinV](https://answers.ros.org/users/30485/sorinv/) on 2017-07-10**:
I have the same issue. Same type of joint. If i remove the transmission the problem is not there anymore but i cannot control the joint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It seems to be a bug, I proposed a fix for it:
https://github.com/ros-simulation/gazebo_ros_pkgs/pull/588

---

Originally posted by [cyborg-x1](https://answers.ros.org/users/1900/cyborg-x1/) with karma: 1376 on 2017-05-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I managed to use `velocity_controllers/JointPositionController` instead of `position_controllers/JointPositionController` with the prismatic joint. You just need to add a PID for it. Here's an example.

Before:

```
arm_controller:
  type: "position_controllers/JointPositionController"
  joint: arm_joint
```

After:

```
arm_controller:
  type: "velocity_controllers/JointPositionController"
  joint: arm_joint
  pid: {p: 100.0, i: 0.01, d: 1.0}
```

And for the transmission:

```
<hardwareInterface>hardware_interface/VelocityJointInterface </hardwareInterface>
```

---

Originally posted by [SorinV](https://answers.ros.org/users/30485/sorinv/) with karma: 106 on 2017-07-10

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1